# Error using multi_query "Call to a member function multi_query() on a non-object "

Tags: php, sql, object, multi-query

I'm looking for an explanation / fix for this error. I'm using the following script. This is my first time using multi_query :

```
        $storyidr=$_POST['storyidr'];
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
 if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))
   {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
$sql  = "INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) VALUES ('$_POST[storyidr]','$_POST[value]',now());"; 
$sql .= "SELECT AVG(rank) AS avrank from ratings WHERE storyidr = $storyidr";
if($mysqli->multi_query($sql))
{   
if ($result = $mysqli->store_result())
{ 
$data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$avrank = $data['avrank'];
        if(!$result)
        {
              $arr = array ('status'=>'fail');
              echo json_encode($arr);
        }
        else
        {

                echo json_encode($avrank);
        }
                exit;
}
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: As it stands, your code is open to [**SQL injection**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `$mysqli` is not defined, you are assigning it to `$con`,
Change from

```
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
```

to

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpasswd,$database_name) or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
```

Comment: Also, `if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))` to `if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli))`

Comment: That did rid error, thank you! Script not working though. You wouldn't happen to notice any other problems here? I'm editing ? to post current code. When use triggers aJax, an empty value displays (no data)